# How can I remove underline of link using CSS and JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

There are four links with `<a>` label in my webpage, I hope to redirect to new webpage and remove the underline of the link when I click a link.

The Code A can  redirect new webpage when I click a link, but the underline of the link can't be removed.

The Code B can remove the underline of the link when I click  a link, but webpage can't be  redirected, how to fix it?

**Code A**

```
       $(function () {
            $(".mainMenu").click(function () {
                $(".mainMenu").removeClass("mainMenuSelected").addClass("mainMenu");        
                $(this).addClass("mainMenuSelected");
            });
        });



   <a id="id_home"  href="/Default.aspx"  class="mainMenu" >Home</a>
    <a id="id_demo"  href="/Demo.aspx"  class="mainMenu">Demo</a>
    <a id="id_help"  href="/Help.aspx"  class="mainMenu">Help</a>
    <a id="id_about" href="/About.aspx"  class="mainMenu">About</a>

.mainMenu {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;    
}


.mainMenuSelected {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Blue;
}
```

**Code B**

```
       $(function () {
            $(".mainMenu").click(function () {
                $(".mainMenu").removeClass("mainMenuSelected").addClass("mainMenu");        
                $(this).removeAttr("href").addClass("mainMenuSelected");
            });
        });

...//The same
```

**Added Content:**

The following Code C is my answer, it works well.

**Code C**

```
$(function () {
            var filename = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();

            switch (filename.toUpperCase()) {
                case "Default.aspx".toUpperCase():
                    setMainMenuSelected("#id_home");
                    break;

                case "":
                    setMainMenuSelected("#id_home");
                    break;

                case "Demo.aspx".toUpperCase():
                    setMainMenuSelected("#id_demo");
                    break;

                case "Help.aspx".toUpperCase():
                    setMainMenuSelected("#id_help");
                    break;

                case "About.aspx".toUpperCase():
                    setMainMenuSelected("#id_about");
                    break;

            }

        });

        function setMainMenuSelected(id) {
            $(id).removeAttr("href").addClass("mainMenuSelected");
        }
```

Comment: I assume, that you are going to a different page, when clicking the link, right? But you remove the underline in the page, where you clicked the link, not in the page, which you go to. So, the page you go to would need to have the mainMenuSelected class set by default on the link, which leads to the page. If I understood your setup correctly.

Comment: Must I write code in each webpage ? such as Default.aspx, Demo.aspx, Help.aspx and About.aspx ?

Comment: How does jQuery know which webapge is loaded?

Comment: @HelloCW no, you don't have to repeat the code in each page, if you put the menu and anything else you want to appear on every page into the [master page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100)).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Javascript to solve this. I'd do it right in the HTML code which creates your menu.

You can compare `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath`, which contains the path portion of the URL of the page you’re currently viewing, with the `href` of each menu item.

```
<a id="id_home" href="/Default.aspx" class="mainMenu <% HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Default.aspx" ? "mainMenuSelected" : "" %>">Home</a>
<a id="id_demo" href="/Demo.aspx" class="mainMenu <% HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Demo.aspx" ? "mainMenuSelected" : "" %>">Demo</a>
<a id="id_help" href="/Help.aspx" class="mainMenu <% HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Help.aspx" ? "mainMenuSelected" : "" %>">Help</a>
<a id="id_about" href="/About.aspx" class="mainMenu <% HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/About.aspx" ? "mainMenuSelected" : "" %>">About</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! But somethimes the Default.aspx can be omit

Comment: Then you can omit it in your code too: `<a id="id_home" href="/" class="mainMenu <% HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/" ? "mainMenuSelected" : "" %>">Home</a>`

Comment: Is it a good way to use `localStorage` passing information between differents webpage?

Comment: Thanks! but your code can't be compiled.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question based your code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  $(".mainMenu").click(function () {
      $('.mainMenu').removeClass("mainMenuSelected");       
      $(this).toggleClass("mainMenuSelected");        
      $(this).removeAttr("href");
  });
});
```

```css
.mainMenu {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;   
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.mainMenuSelected {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="id_home"  href="/Default.aspx"  class="mainMenu" >Home</a>
<a id="id_demo"  href="/Demo.aspx"  class="mainMenu">Demo</a>
<a id="id_help"  href="/Help.aspx"  class="mainMenu">Help</a>
<a id="id_about" href="/About.aspx"  class="mainMenu">About</a>
```

I hope helps this solution. please check.

Comment: And more, I think your code will not work well because  a new webpage will be loaded and  
`$(function () {...} `  will be fired in new webpage when you click `<a id="id_demo"  href="/Demo.aspx"  class="mainMenu">Demo</a>`